# Switch statement behaving differently on Vercel and in local. Using React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, rendering

Hello everyone and thank you for your time,

On the first render of the App in Vercel the "sortBy" isn't applied. When selecting different options from the dropdown that controls the state the page doesn't update, only on the next selection the page will update but then the selection won't match with what appears on the screen.

When the app is loaded, the data is displayed like it's fetched. Upon changing the "sortBy" state the sorting incorrectly updates to the initial state option. Subsequent changes to the state do nothing, until I change it one more time, and then the data get sorted according to the state before the latest one.

This does not happen when running on local machine.

My code is below. Please keep in mind that I am new to coding in general, and especially to React. Thank you for understanding.

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import { Stack, Grid, Pagination, Snackbar } from "@mui/material";
import ShowCard from "./ShowCard";
import Settings from "./Settings";

const paginationReducer = (_, action) => {
  return {
    page: action.page,
    from: action.page * 24 - 24,
    to: action.page * 24,
  };
};

const LandingPage = ({ allShows, openDrawer, selectedGenres, minRating }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const currentPage = +useParams().page.slice(-1);

  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("rating hi-low");
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [paginationState, dispatchPagination] = useReducer(paginationReducer, {
    page: 1,
    from: 0,
    to: 24,
  });
  const [openSnackbar, setOpenSnackbar] = useState(false);
  const [snackbarContent, setSnackbarContent] = useState("");

  const handleOpen = (message) => {
    setOpenSnackbar(true);
    setSnackbarContent(message);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenSnackbar(false);
    setSnackbarContent("");
  };

  const handlePageChange = (_, newPage) => {
    dispatchPagination({ page: newPage });
    navigate(`/page-${newPage}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handlePageChange(null, currentPage);
  }, [currentPage]);

  let filteredShows;
  let totalPages;

  if (selectedGenres.length) {
    filteredShows = allShows.filter((show) =>
      show.genres.some((genre) =>
        selectedGenres.some((selectedGenre) => selectedGenre === genre)
      )
    );
    totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredShows.length / 24);
  } else {
    filteredShows = allShows.slice();
    totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredShows.length / 24);
  }

  if (minRating > 1) {
    filteredShows = filteredShows.filter(
      (show) => show.rating.average >= minRating
    );
    totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredShows.length / 24);
  } else {
    filteredShows = filteredShows.slice();
  }

  const displayShows = searchQuery
    ? searchResults
    : filteredShows.slice(paginationState.from, paginationState.to);

  switch (sortBy) {
    case "name a-z":
      allShows.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
      break;
    case "name z-a":
      allShows.sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name));
      break;
    case "rating low-hi":
      allShows.sort((a, b) => a.rating.average - b.rating.average);
      break;
    case "rating hi-low":
    default:
      allShows.sort((a, b) => b.rating.average - a.rating.average);
  }

  const searchShows = (query) => {
    if (query) {
      const searchedShows = filteredShows.filter((show) =>
        show.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
      );
      setSearchResults(searchedShows);
    } else {
      setSearchResults([]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Stack alignItems="center">
      <Settings
        sortBy={sortBy}
        setSortBy={setSortBy}
        openDrawer={openDrawer}
        searchQuery={searchQuery}
        setSearchQuery={setSearchQuery}
        searchShows={searchShows}
      />
      <Grid container spacing={3} p={4} component="main">
        {displayShows.map((show) => (
          <Grid item key={show.id} xl={2} lg={3} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
            <ShowCard show={show} displaySnackbar={handleOpen} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
      {!searchQuery && (
        <Pagination
          sx={{ p: 1 }}
          variant="outlined"
          shape="rounded"
          size="large"
          page={paginationState.page}
          count={totalPages}
          onChange={handlePageChange}
        />
      )}
      <Snackbar
        open={openSnackbar}
        autoHideDuration={2500}
        onClose={handleClose}
        message={snackbarContent}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Tried looking on the Internet for solution, but I am not having a good time. This is just a personal project for my CV.

Full app code: https://github.com/RadosRosic/BitShowMUI
Vercel link: https://bit-show-seven.vercel.app/page-1

Any feedback to my code is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was that allShows state was being mutated directly.

This has been resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).